# STM32L4 drive voltage randomly(?) too low

Tags: voltage, stm32, signal

Not really sure where to even begin with this one. Last night when I turned everything off, the STM32L432 Nucleo board I've been working with drives high to 3V. When I turned it on this morning--no other differences--I'm only getting a 1V high signal. I'm new enough that I might not be understanding something simple here, but how is this possible?

Today:
[image]

Yesterday (lamentably, different code as I didn't save a capture of the current program, but still you can see that the voltage is better):
[image]

Comment: What is the measured supply voltage for these two cases?

Comment: Both cases I am plugged into USB power

Comment: Just because you're plugged into USB doesn't mean what's on the micro is 3V3. Maybe it's scope settings?

Comment: USB provides 5V. It appears that your board actually runs at 3V or 3.3V. Use a voltmeter to measure the actual supply voltage to the processor for both cases.

Comment: Is anything hot? Are there any external voltages applied before USB power?

Comment: Have you put it on something conducting accidentally? Have you removed the Idd jumper because you wanted to measure the current and have forgotten to put it in again? This'll become an ugly question...

Comment: Use the same instrument to measure one of the supply pins, thus ruling out changed settings in the instrument.  Disconnect anything you have connected to the SPI.  Write a program which toggles a GPIO and use the instrument to measure that.

Comment: It seems to be the LSM sensor breakout I have attached. I have three of them and the other two get full voltage. Oddly, I didn't unhook this one last night, so some magical gnome apparently came to my house and broke it while I slept?